# GoTo Meeting on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, activex, meetings

How to make it work GotoMeeting.com on ubuntu? . I know that its  not support ubuntu .

**Question 1** : is any other way or cheating way to acheive this ?

**My investgation reg this :**

Because, Goto Meetings  installs some ActiveX controls in the system.

ActiveX is the technology by MS, so it supports only Windows.

ActiveX controls can not be installed in linux.

So, gotomeeting.com wont work under Linux.

**Question 1.1** Then is there a way to use ActiveX through WINE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install a Virtual version of Windows and run it from there

If you don't have a Windows license [try these evaluation versions.](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) I just need to find out whether you can use these under Linux (whether it works).

[FAQ:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb738381.aspx)

- Q.   Is there a cost to use VHDs for evaluations?
- A. No. The VHDs are available as a free download from www.microsoft.com/vhd.
- Q.   How long is the evaluation period for the VHD?
- A.   Open evaluations for customers will enable a 30-day evaluation time period for a VHD running on Windows Server 2003 and a 60-day evaluation time period for a VHD running on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Where i can get virtual version of windows

Comment: Install Windows 7 RC in your Virtual PC: done!

Comment: Now that does sound reasonable for anyone who already has a Windows license... but I guess a 'hack' / trick would be a better solution.

Comment: Would this image work as a "full" version:http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en ?

Comment: Use https://github.com/xdissent/ievms.git to create a VirtualBox VM with an evaluation license of Windows.  It automatically creates a snapshot prior to activation that you can rollback to reset the evaluation period.

Answer (score 1):

GoToMeeting only offers clients for Windows and Mac.

People are reporting that the Windows client doesn't work under Wine: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=642095&page=2